# Passing data from table view controller to view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having issues with moving from a table view controller to a view controller to display information about a particular cell that was selected.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SentDetailView" {
        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as NSIndexPath
        let referrals = referralsSent[indexPath.row]

        let destViewController = segue.destination as! SentDetailViewController
        destViewController.referringTo = referrals.referTo
        destViewController.patientsName = referrals.patientsName
        //print("Contained value during segue " + destViewController.patientsName!)
        destViewController.patientsPhoneNumber = referrals.patientsNumber
        destViewController.patientsEmail = referrals.patientsEmail
        destViewController.comments = referrals.comment
    }
}
```

Storyboard setup:

[image: Storyboard setup]

I get the following results:

[image: Result]

I select a cell and it just highlights and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `didSelectRowAt` and call `performSegue` with sender as the selected index path. Try this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SentDetailView", sender: indexPath)        
}
```

And this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SentDetailView"{
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        let referrals = referralsSent[indexPath.row]

        let destViewController = segue.destination as! SentDetailViewController
        destViewController.referringTo = referrals.referTo
        destViewController.patientsName = referrals.patientsName
        //print("Contained value during segue " + destViewController.patientsName!)
        destViewController.patientsPhoneNumber = referrals.patientsNumber
        destViewController.patientsEmail = referrals.patientsEmail
        destViewController.comments = referrals.comment
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew I should have messed with didSelectRowAt, but I saw some tutorials that worked without. Either way, thanks! It works